# EnableLowerCamelCase when using ODataModelBuilder

Tags: json, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

Turning the JSON result into camelCase is easy when using `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
```

But how is it done when using `ODataModelBuilder`? I can't seem to find anything on the topic.

I suspect it has to be done per Property, a bit like this `builder...Property(x => x.Foo)...` but can't find any relevant method.

Comment: Why would you want to use `ODataModelBuilder`? The `ODataConventionModelBuilder` derives from it.

Comment: Because I'm only exposing a subset of my domain model and I'd have to write a lot of code to make it build using ODataConventionModelBuilder